# The meanings of English idioms

Tags: sentence-meaning

What's the meaning of '***go all the way (to sth/swh)***'? It is written in 'Destination B2' without explanation and I couldn't find it anywhere. Could you please give the definition with some examples?

Comment: Was there a complete sentence? What was it? Do you have any research? You can [edit] your question to include more details. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *go all the way* means to continue a progress until its completion, whether that be literally geographical (as a final destination) or not (as in the completion of a task).

Additionally, to "go all the way" (at least in American English) has a sexual connotation of achieving coitus.

Comment: As a footnote, it's usually a standalone expression, that is, the "to something" or "to somewhere" is typically omitted.